# WinUSB Installation

Tags: windows, usb, driver, winusb

I wanted to experiment a bit with WinUSB. I've installed the WinDDK and I'm about to create my first INF-file for my driver. I'm following the [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this. The guide contains a sample INF file and the instructions to "changing USB_Install in section names to an appropriate DDInstall value".

Fair enough, only problem is I have no idea what 'appropriate DDInstall values' are.

I'm not really an expert with INF files and I can only guess that the guide probably wants me to change the section names in the sample file

```
[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT
```

to something different than `[USB_Install]` in the section header. The only explanation about DDInstall I found is just a general explanation on what to do with this section ([Also on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

My question is, what I'm I supposed to put into my INF file instead of the `[USB_Install]` string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried to follow the same MSDN guide and ran into a few issues. I ended up using Microchip's WinUSB driver template. This template can be found in the [Microchip Application Libraries](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784).

It's a bit different from the example given by MSDN but it works on my system. It also works with the tools and dll files which come with the latest WDK (version 8.0).

Although this does not address your question, I think it's a better template to work from compared to the one provided by MSDN.

Here is the inf file Microchip provides:

```
;This .inf file is a modified version of the example INF provided
;in the Microsoft document:
;"How to Use WinUSB to Communicate with a USB Device"


[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class = CustomUSBDevices
ClassGuid= {a503e2d3-a031-49dc-b684-c99085dbfe92}
Provider = %MFGNAME%
DriverVer=07/20/2012,1.0.0.4
CatalogFile=winusb.cat    ;CAT file needed for a signed driver pacakage
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Manufacturer]
%MFGNAME% = MyDevice_WinUSB,NTx86,NTamd64

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  Vendor and Product ID Definitions
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; When developing your custom USB device, the VID and PID used in the PC side
; application program and the firmware on the microcontroller must match.
; Modify the below lines to use your VID and PID.  Use the format as shown below.
; Note: One INF file can be used for multiple devices with different VID and PIDs.
; For each supported device, append ",USB\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy" to the end of the line.
; There is a maximum number of devices that can be supported per line however.
; If you append a large number of VID/PIDs to the end of the line, and get a:
; "The data area passed to a system call is too small." error when trying to install
; the INF, try removing some of the VIDs/PIDs.
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[MyDevice_WinUSB.NTx86]
%DESCRIPTION% =USB_Install, USB\VID_04d8&PID_0204

[MyDevice_WinUSB.NTamd64]
%DESCRIPTION% =USB_Install, USB\VID_04d8&PID_0204


;=========================================================================================
;ClassInstall32 and ClassInstall_AddReg sections used to make new device manager category.
;=========================================================================================
[ClassInstall32]
AddReg=ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,,%DEVICEMANAGERCATEGORY%
HKR,,Icon,,"-20"


; =================== Installation ===================

[USB_Install]
Include=winusb.inf
Needs=WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include=winusb.inf
AddService=WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService=WINUSB, WinUsb_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion=1.11

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg=Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{58D07210-27C1-11DD-BD0B-0800200C9a66}"
;When editing the GUID (the big hex number with dashes inside the squiggly 
;braces), make sure to write the intended PC application to use the same GUID.
;Otherwise the application won't be able to find the USB device properly.

[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg=CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles=CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01011.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

; ================= Source Media Section =====================

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll=1
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll=1

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll=2
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll=2

; =================== Strings ===================

[Strings]
MFGNAME="Your Manufacturer Name" ; ManufacturerName
DESCRIPTION="Your USB Device Name" ; DeviceName
WinUSB_SvcDesc="WinUSB Device"
DISK_NAME="WinUSB Device Install Disk" ; DiskName
DEVICEMANAGERCATEGORY="Custom USB Devices" ; ClassName
```

Comment: I tried using your template (with a few modifications) and you resolved a huge issue I was having! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127992/usb-driver-installation-issue-for-microcontroller-using-custom-inf

You're awesome. :)

Comment: Good job. There is no end to how many ways microsoft can suck.

Comment: Can you explain why class was "CustomUSBDevices" instead of "UsbDevice"? And is that a standard Microsoft class or one you created?